# Copying audio into general UIPasteboard

Tags: ios, uipasteboard, generalpasteboard, mapi-audiocopy, mapi-audiopaste

I am implementing Audio Copy feature in my audio synthesis app using the general UIPasteboard so that the audio that was copied can be pasted in **MAPI: AudioCopy/AudioPaste** or **Intua Audio Sharing** enabled apps. There seems to be a problem in the process and the copied audio does not appear in a AudioPaste enabled app.

This is what I am doing to copy the audio into the general UIPasteboard.

```
NSData *newItemData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:[dataPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"converted.wav"]];      


// This is the copy operation using the General Pasteboard otherwise known as the Intua Pasteboard
UIPasteboard *board = [UIPasteboard generalPasteboard];
[board setPersistent:TRUE];
NSData *dataFile = newItemData;

if (!dataFile) {
    NSLog(@"Can't open file");
}

// Create chunked data and append to clipboard
NSUInteger sz = [dataFile length];
NSUInteger chunkNumbers = (sz / GP_CLIPBOARD_CHUNK_SIZE) + 1;
NSMutableArray *items = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:chunkNumbers];
NSRange curRange;

for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < chunkNumbers; i++) {
    curRange.location = i * GP_CLIPBOARD_CHUNK_SIZE;
    curRange.length = MIN(GP_CLIPBOARD_CHUNK_SIZE, sz - curRange.location);
    NSData *subData = [dataFile subdataWithRange:curRange];
    NSDictionary *dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:subData forKey:(NSString *)kUTTypeAudio];
    [items addObject:dict];
}

board.items = items;
```

After doing this step, when I launch an AudioPaste compatible app, I do not see the audio I just copied. Could you spot any fault in my Audio Copy code?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not convinced that your path you're creating by adding "converted.wav" exists. I would check that the file path exists before continuing through with the copy. You may find that path looks something like "myAudioFile.wavconverted.wav".

As a minor note, the General Pasteboard that's returned by [UIPasteboard generalPasteboard] is always persistent, so you don't need to set it to persistent.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. "converted.wav" indeed does exist. I've debugged and seen that newItemData is getting some bytes. I'm doing some checks too for file's existence. I've removed the code to post here for conciseness sake.